# How to test the resolved parameter set?

Tags: powershell, pester

I'm trying to write a basic Pester test that checks an "advanced" function for the resolved parameter set:

```
function Do-Stuff
{
    [CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName='Set 1')]
    [OutputType([String])]

    Param
    (
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='Set 1')] 
        [switch]
        $S1,

        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='Set 2')]
        [switch]
        $S2
    )

    $PSBoundParameters |select -ExpandProperty Keys
}

Describe Do-Stuff {
    It 'Returns "S2" when switch "S2" is set' {
        $actual = Do-Stuff -S2 
        $expexted = 'S2'
        $actual |Should Be $expexted
    }

    # How to test the resolved parameter set?
    It 'The resolved parameter set is "Set 2" when switch "S2" is set' { 
        $actual = 'What to do here?' # I'm lost ;(
        $expexted = 'Set 2'
        $actual |Should Be $expexted
    }
}
```

Thanx. Any advice would be highly appreciated since I'm totally new to Pester. ...not much better in posh and coding in general either :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following will test if **you** use 'Set 2' for parameter S2:

```
Describe Do-Stuff {
    $Command = Get-Command 'Do-Stuff'

    It 'Returns "S2" when switch "S2" is set' {
        $actual = Do-Stuff -S2 
        $expexted = 'S2'
        $actual |Should Be $expexted
    }

# How to test the resolved parameter set?
    It 'The resolved parameter set is "Set 2" when switch "S2" is set' { 
        $actual = $Command.Parameters["S2"].ParameterSets.Keys
        $expexted = 'Set 2'
        $actual |Should Be $expexted
        # when you use several sets for parameters
        $expexted -contains $actual | should Be $true
   }
```

}

Tracing if powershell is actually executing 'set 2', when you set it so, not a subject for pester testing imho...

Answer (score 2):

You would use [the `Trace-Command` cmdlet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849955.aspx) for this.

The `-Name` parameter would be set to `ParameterBinderController`.

As a way to get started, try something like this (outside of pester)

```
Trace-Command -Name ParameterBinderController -Expression { Do-Stuff -S2 } -PSHost
```

The `-PSHost` options sends the output to the host so you can see it.

You will probably want to not use that in your Pester test, and experiment with the other listener options and methods of catching the output.

Comment: Updated the answer to use `ParameterBinderController` instead of `ParameterBinding` since it's easier to see the parameter set name that way.

Comment: thanx. that's way over my league :D I was wondering if there might be some simple and relatively elegant solution. been playing with posh these days -- trying to make a "wrapper" for a cmd app and a json-rpc client for it, both having nearly 50+ parameters/options/methods. plus I wanted to have a look at pester

Comment: @JaquelineVanek I think this could work for you. If you're writing Pester tests then `Trace-Command` is not out of your league. I would love to see a Pester test for this actually; I think it would be really useful.

Comment: @briantist Did you find a way to get `Trace-Command` to return an object describing parameter binding that you could interrogate?  Then you could just write `$traceCommandOutput.ParameterSetName | Should be 'desiredParameterSetName'`.  It seems like that ability should exist somewhere...

Comment: @alx9r I havent tried that. Maybe remove `-PSHost` and look at different output options?

Answer (score 0):

Use as follows:

```
Function Main{
  [CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess=$true,DefaultParameterSetName="ViewOnly")]
Param(

[Parameter(ParameterSetName="ViewOnly")]
   [switch]$ViewOnly,

[Parameter(ParameterSetName="NukeAll")]
 [switch]$NukeAll
)

Switch ($PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName){
 "NukeAll"{
NukeAll
 }#end nuke all
"ViewOnly"{
ViewOnly
}#end viewonly
  }#end Switch

Function NukeAll {
  #Do NukeAll function code here.
 }

Function ViewOnly{
  #Do ViewOnly function code here.
 }
```

Comment: dont think you got me. mah bad, sorry